# TSQL pivot issue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

Hello I have a temp table (`@tempResult`) that contains results like the following...

```
-----------------------------------------
| DrugAliasID | Dosage1 | Unit1 | rowID | 
-----------------------------------------
| 322         | 10      | MG    | 1     |
| 322         | 50      | ML    | 2     |
| 441         | 20      | ML    | 3     |
| 443         | 15      | ML    | 4     |
-----------------------------------------
```

I'm looking to get the results to be like the following, pivoting the rows that have the same `DrugAliasID`.

```
--------------------------------------------------
| DrugAliasID | Dosage1 | Unit1 | Dosage2 | Unit2 |
--------------------------------------------------
| 322         | 10      | MG    | 50      | ML    |
| 441         | 20      | ML    | NULL    | NULL  |
| 443         | 15      | ML    | NULL    | NULL  |
--------------------------------------------------
```

So far I have a solution that isn't using pivot. I'm not too good with pivot and was wondering if anyone knew how to use it in this scenario. Or solve it some other way. Thanks

```
SELECT  
    tr.drugAliasID, 
    MIN(trmin.dosage1) AS dosage1,
    MIN(trmin.unit1) AS unit1,
    MIN(trmax.dosage1) AS dosage2,
    MIN(trmax.unit1) AS unit2
FROM 
    @tempResult tr
JOIN 
    @tempResult trmin ON trmin.RowID = tr.rowid AND trmin.drugAliasID = tr.drugAliasID
JOIN 
    @tempResult trmax ON trmax.RowID = tr.rowid AND trmax.drugAliasID = tr.drugAliasID
JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         MIN(RowID) AS rowid,
         drugAliasID 
     FROM 
         @tempResult 
     GROUP BY 
         drugAliasID) tr1 ON tr1.rowid = trmin.RowID
JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         MAX(RowID) AS rowid,
         drugAliasID 
     FROM 
         @tempResult 
     GROUP BY 
         drugAliasID) tr2 ON tr2.rowid = tr.RowID
GROUP BY 
    tr.drugAliasID
HAVING 
    count(tr.drugAliasID) > 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your version of SQL Server supports the use of CTEs, you can simplify your query thus:

```
;with cte as
(select *, row_number() over (partition by drugaliasid order by rowid) rn
 from @tempResult
)

select c.drugaliasid, c.dosage1, c.unit1, c2.dosage1 as dosage2, c2.unit1 as unit2
from cte c
left join cte c2 on c.drugaliasid = c2.drugaliasid and c.rn = 1 and c2.rn = 2
where c.rn = 1
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/UKMB71171)

This will give you the desired result, without having to use the pivot keyword.

Comment: @mgmedick You're welcome. Remember to tag your future questions with the appropriate database version, so that version-specific solutions can be posted :)